# error :- test: ing: unary operator expected

Tags: bash, shell, unix

below is my script to run some sub commands. When i am running the script with `./test.sh sub_cmd $APP` it is running fine. But when i ran it like `test sub_cmd $APP` it throwing an error.

I want to run the script without using `./`

`error :- test: ing: unary operator expected`

```
#!/bin/bash

ProgName=$(basename $0)

APP=${2?Need chart name}

sub_help(){
    echo "Usage: $ProgName <subcommand> [options]\n"

}

sub_dep(){
    echo "Running 'dep' command."
    vi some_path/${APP}/templates/deployment.yaml
}

sub_ing(){
    echo "Running 'ing' command."
    vi some_path/${APP}/templates/ingress.yaml
}

sub_svc(){
    echo "Running 'ing' command."
    vi some_path/${APP}/templates/service.yaml
}
subcommand=$1
case $subcommand in
    "" | "-h" | "--help")
        sub_help
        ;;
    *)
        shift
        sub_${subcommand} $@
        if [ $? = 127 ]; then
            echo "Error: '$subcommand' is not a known subcommand." >&2
            echo "       Run '$ProgName --help' for a list of known subcommands." >&2
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run "test.sh" not "test".

```
test sub_cmd $APP
```

What you are actually running is the test command which lives in one of the lib directories on your path.

If you type

```
which test
```

you can see which command/script/program that will be run.

When you prefix the command with a relative path (such as ./) or an absolute path (ie.e starting with a /) then bash will look in that specific folder for the command. If you omit the path then it will search the directories listed in the environment variable $PATH and execute the first one it comes across. The which command does the same thing, but just lists the script/program instead of executing it.

Comment: Also, naming a script some variant of "test" is a bad idea, precisely because it'll cause confusion like this.